# validation of formvalue data in golang

Tags: validation, go, echo

I am getting data in the post request as a form data and i want to validate that data before i send that data to the Database query.
How can i do that.

I can see that i can use validator with json type by binding.

This is my game struct:

```
type Game struct {
    Id           string `json:"Id"`
    Name         string `json:"Name" validate:"required"`
    Rating       float32 `json:"Rating" `
    TimesPlayed  int `json:"TimesPlayed" validate:"required, number"`
    ImagePath    string `json:"ImagePath" validate:"required, file"`
    Description  string `json:"Description"`
    Developer    string `json:"Developer" validate:"required, min=5, max=20"`
    CreationDate time.Time `json:"CreationDate"`
    Version      string `json:"Version"`
    Tags         []string `json:"Tags"`
    Downloads    int64 `json:"Downloads" validate:"number"` // firestore doesn't support uint64
    DownloadLink string `json:"DownloadLink" validate:"required, uri"`
}
```

I have formvalue and i want to take advantage of validator to validate my formvalue.

Any guide on how can i do this?

Right now i am doing this without validation

```
func newGameHandler(c echo.Context) error {
    // create new game model
    // TODO need a security layer in between the form and our new game struct
    newGame := models.Game{
        Name:         c.FormValue(NAME),
        Developer:    c.FormValue(DEVELOPER),
        CreationDate: time.Now(),
        Version:      c.FormValue(VERSION),
    }
    

    // Add new game to database
    _db, getDbErr := db.NewDatabaseFromEnv()
    _, err := _db.AddGame(newGame)

    // error handling
    if getDbErr != nil {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, "Database connection error")
    }
    if err != nil {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, "Database add game error")
    }

    // TODO return successful game add
    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, "New game handler")
}
```

how can i add validation on this?

Comment: Here is the document of `echo` about validating data. https://echo.labstack.com/guide/request/#validate-data

Answer (score 0):

It's depends on what framework you are using but we have [Go-validator](https://github.com/go-playground/validator) for general purposes, also based on framework you are using you can use their validator too, like [echo-validator](https://echo.labstack.com/guide/request/#validate-data) or [gin-validator](https://blog.logrocket.com/gin-binding-in-go-a-tutorial-with-examples/#basic-validation-using-gin).

You can add your custom validation function to them too.

Comment: Thank you for response. It seems the validator in go or echo does not support for formdata and i wanted to know best way or any sample for doing form data

Comment: You should see [This](https://echo.labstack.com/guide/binding/)
,you need to add form tag to your struct and use echo validators in bind